# Failing to find DC servers and their disk usage

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

so i got stuck with this assignment where i need to find all DC servers and their disk ussage

i tried first to get all the DC servers and then add the disk usage info but it doesn't work

```
$getdomain = [System.Directoryservices.Activedirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain() 
$getdomain | ForEach-Object {$_.DomainControllers} |  
ForEach-Object { 
$hEntry= [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($_.Name) 
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{ 
  Name = $_.Name 
  IPAddress = $hEntry.AddressList[0].IPAddressToString 
 } 
} | get-wmiobject -class win32_logicaldisk | select-object pscomputername,deviceid,freespace,size
```

Comment: Can you expand on "doesn't work" - what happens? Do you get partial output? Do you get _unexpected_ output? Are there any errors? If so, what does the error message say?  Please remember you're the only one who can see your screen :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the task you have you have some useless code lines in your code. Did you copy the code from somewhere?  ;-)
I'd recommend to take your time to start learning the very basics of Powershell first.

That's actually all you need:

```
$DCList = [System.Directoryservices.Activedirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain().DomainControllers
foreach ($DC in $DCList) {
    Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $DC.Name | 
        Select-Object -Property pscomputername, deviceid, freespace, size
}
```

Conclusion: You should remove what you have inside the loop from your copied code and replace it with what you have added at the end. ;-)

Comment: @Lyoxa_grimm That depends pretty much on your level. For beginners: [Getting Started with PowerShell](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/GetStartedPowerShell3)  ... or if you like to read [Windows PowerShell™ 4: TFM](https://www.sapien.com/books_training/Windows-PowerShell-4). Don't worry if it's not about version 5.1 or 7.0 - the basics are still the same. ;-)

Comment: Great man! thanks! i started a new job like a month ago and i use powershell a lot mostly editng existing scripts but lately i get assignments that require me to write scripts from scratch hope these videos will help

Comment: If you're working on a machine that has the Active Directory PowerShell module installed, you can simply use the Get-ADDomainController cmdlet to return all the DCs in your organisation.